# How do I query an external GraphQL endpoint in Gatsby JS?

Tags: graphql-js, gatsby

I don't seen any clear way to query an outside GraphQL endpoint (i.e. https://somewebsite.com/graphql) for data.  Has anyone else done this, and how did you do it?

I assume it requires you to build a custom plugin, but that seems overkill for such a simple need.  I have searched the docs and this issue doesn't really ever get addressed.

Comment: I've looked at using apollo fetch, but that approach isn't very gatsby-ish, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

In Gatsby V2 you don't need to create your own plugin.

What you need is a plugin called gatsby-source-graphql

> gatsby-source-graphql uses schema stitching to combine the schema of a
>   third-party API with the Gatsby schema.

You can find more info [here.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-09-25-announcing-graphql-stitching-support/)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, as you mentioned, writing a new source plugin. This is how Gatsby gets the data into it's internal GraphQL structure to then query.

Plugins are, at their core, just additions to the gatsby-node, gatsby-browser, and gatsby-ssr files. So you could write the logic needed at the top of your gatsby-node file to avoid abstracting it out into it's own plugin.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also query external GraphQL endpoints as discussed with @sarasate. However, they will not be included in Gatsby's static data, and so won't be pre-fetched, removing most of the benefit of using Gatsby in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not so into writing plugins for gatsby, like me, have a look [here](https://medium.com/@dwalsh.sdlr/gatsby-apollo-graphcool-netlify-the-webs-promised-land-6dd510efbd72).
It explains in detail how you query any graphQL server via the Gatsby `sourceNode` API and the use of [graphql-request](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-request).

Helped me to get data for e.g. from graph.cool as well as GraphCMS.

The problem though is that you always have to write 2 different kinds of graphQL queries, as they are usually not compatible to Gatsby's relay style queries. But still easier than building a whole plugin.

Comment: Thanks Sarasate.  I found this article too... and I came to the same conclusion.  I will probably use this approach, though I still think it might be useful to learn the ins-and-outs of Gatsby plugin creation, just to have a more solid understanding.  Thanks for chiming in.